# Не собираеться проект из DirectX Sample Browser

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, directx

В общем дочитал книгу до второй части [DirectX 10 - это просто. Программируем графику на С++](http://www.bhv.ru/books/book.php?id=182868). Где автор начинает работать с DXUT (DirectX Sample Browser)

Увы у меня не получилось сразу же запустить проект EmptyProject10.

*Сами решения на VS2008 и VS2010.*

Первая ошибка:

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  C2668   abs: неоднозначный вызов перегруженной функции  EmptyProject12  C:\Dima\DirectX\Projects\DirectXSamples\EmptyProject12\DXUT\Core\DXUTenum.cpp   3976
```

Было

```
float fCurRanking = abs( float( displayMode.RefreshRate.Numerator ) / fDenom1  -  
 float(refreshRateMatch.Numerator ) / fDenom2 );
```

Стало

```
float fCurRanking = fabs( float( displayMode.RefreshRate.Numerator ) / float(fDenom1)  -
float( refreshRateMatch.Numerator ) / float(fDenom2) );
```

---

после появились ошибки **LNK2001** и **LNK1120** :

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "__vsnwprintf" EmptyProject12  C:\Dima\DirectX\Projects\DirectXSamples\EmptyProject12\dxerr.lib(dxerrw.obj)    1   

Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1  EmptyProject12  C:\Dima\DirectX\Projects\DirectXSamples\EmptyProject12\Release\EmptyProject12.exe   1
```

Также замечу что не получается прописать в файлах проекта, директории библиотек (**просто отсутствует кнопка `ок` и `применить` 0_о**)

Как их решить ??? Почему не собирается (ведь всё по книге) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Надо создавать отдельный проект в него надо подключить библиотеки 
  dll-ки также заголовочные файлы к ним.
- Подключить либо перенести все файлы из проекта EmptyProject10,также не забыть прописать пути в свойствах проекта (\DXUT\Core,\DXUT\Optional).
- В файле EmptyProject10.cpp в самом верху вставить строку подключения библиотеки `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib`

  #pragma comment(lib, "legacy_stdio_definitions.lib")

  *Эту библиотеку MS предоставила  для включения на странице свойств дополнительных зависимостей эта проблема связанна именно с VS2015 (связать старые версии VS"2010-2013" с новыми начиная с VS2015 )*

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]